# Приложение не устанавливается на телефон android возможные причины

Tags: android

У меня есть приложение на андроид которое я тестировал на виртуальных и реальных устройствах, но вот у меня возникла проблема. Я создаю подписанное приложение а кидаю на телефон, где планирую его поставить, но приложение не устанавливается, при попытке его установить диспетчер установки выводит сообщение что приложение не установлено и все. Дальше я попробовал поставить на такой (проблемный телефон) дебаг версию и эта версия установилась)) я не могу понять в чем проблема - в моем приложении или в телефонах на которые я пытаюсь залить это приложение. Таких телефонов пока-что два но не сильно хочется что-бы из-за моей ошибки в коде приложение не устанавливалось еще на какие-то телефоны. Я пробовал на многих телефонах ставить как релиз так и дебаг, и все устанавливалось нормально, а вот на двух аппаратах почему-то приложение вообще не устанавливается. Если кто-то сталкивался с такой проблемой то буду очень рад полезным советам и ответам.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Короче я решил свою проблему. Я пробовал другие решения, такие как удаление старой/отладочной версии приложения, потому что apk была версией релиза, очищала данные отладочного приложения и даже очищал все мои кэшированные данные. Затем, наконец, я понял, что мне нужно было выбрать обе версии подписи при создании подписанного apk. Я генерировал подписанное приложение, и для подписи нажимал только V2, а нужно было выбирать V1+V2[image: генерация подписанного приложения]
Надеюсь эта информация поможет таким-же начинающим разработчикам как и я))

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте проверить расширения. Пример: у устройства нет SIM, а в приложении как обязательное - работа с SIM картой. Такое приложение не установит диспетчер.

Comment: а может быть проблема в версии андроида?

Comment: @Никита только вот проверять надо не расширения а разрешения